# Sql Query Filter with Or

Tags: sql

```
Select * from Customer Where Acc = '26A' and ( OrderNo = '111' OR OrderNo <> ' ')
```

resluts above query brings

| Acc | Order No |
| --- | --- |
| 26A | 111 |
| 26A | 112 |
| 26A | 113 |

The table data looks like this

| Acc | Order No |
| --- | --- |
| 26A | 111 |
| 26A | 112 |
| 26A | 113 |
| 26B | 114 |
| 26B | 115 |
| 26B | 116 |

I want the query to work so that when I pass the Acc number and Order No it passes only the relevant value entered on the SQL Query, also if the Order No is not entered it should return all the values. At the moment with My query it only filters on the Acc Number.

Comment: The wording of the question is kind of confusing.   I myself can't parse it.

Comment: I want the query to return the Order No and Acc No Value's passed by the query, if AccNo is passed and no Value for Order No is passed it should return all the values in relation with the Passed Acc No on the query. Hope this explains thanks

Comment: Repeating the same unclear question doesn't make it clearer. What do you mean `not entered`? Is it NULL , does it contain an empty string? The query you wrote checks for a space character. An empty string isn't the same as NULL either. You'd have to use `( OrderNo = '111' OR OrderNo IS NULL)` if you want to return all rows where the OrderNo is either 111 or NULL

Comment: Please post an example of the output you want. What do `it passes` and `if the Order No is not entered`  mean? That the row cell is empty? Or that the comparison value is empty? Those are two different cases, requiring different queries. `( OrderNo = '111' OR OrderNo IS NULL)` includes empty cells. `OrderNo=@OrderNo or @OrderNo IS NULL` ignores NULL parameters

Comment: Column OrderNo data type?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use separate queries depending on whether `OrderNo` is *entered* or not:

```
-- OrderNo is not provided
where Acc = @Acc

-- OrderNo is provided
where Acc = @Acc and OrderNo = @OrderNo
```

The other solution is to write your query like so:

```
where Acc = @Acc and (OrderNo = @OrderNo or @OrderNo is null)
```

Where `@OrderNo` parameter must be set to null if the user did not *enter* any value for it. Unfortunately [this approach has issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069277/checking-variable-for-null-kills-performance).

Comment: We need more data structure information to try to understand the problem. For exemple the answer you gave will not give the right result if OrderNo are NULL.

Comment: OP just wants a "catch-all" where clause. Nulls can be handled if OP suggests so.

Comment: We don't know if the OP want's a catch-all, or return matching and empty values. The query is simply unclear. This would solve the catch-all assuming the "missing" value is `''` instead of NULL, which is far more common.

Comment: This is my understanding of the question, `''` vs null need special handling, this I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Every One thanks for all your in puts @PanagiotisKanavos your suggestion to the article really helped this is how I got it working.

```
Select * from Customer Where Acc = '26A' and ( OrderNo = CASE WHEN @OrderNo = '' THEN OrderNo ELSE @OrderNo END)
```